# Removing of multilevel duplicated paths

Tags: python, recursion, path, duplicates

I have a list of products forming a tree (ID, product-name, invoice-type, reference-to-parent-ID):

```
text = """
1,Product1,INVOICE_FEE,
3,Product3,INVOICE_FEE,
7,Product7,DEFAULT,
2,Product2,DEFAULT,7
4,Product4,DEFAULT,7
5,Product5,DEFAULT,2
"""
```

Following code creates paths:

```
lines = [ l.strip() for l in text.strip().splitlines() ]
hierarchy = [ tuple(l.split(',')) for l in lines ]

parents = defaultdict(list)
for p in hierarchy:
    parents[p[3]].append(p)

def pathsMet(parents, node=''):
    childNodes = parents.get(node)
    if not childNodes:
        return [[]]
    paths = []
    for ID, productName, invoiceType, parentID in childNodes:
        for p in pathsMet(parents, ID):
            paths.append([productName] + p)
    return paths
```

List of paths as result:

```
[['Product1'], ['Product3'], ['Product7', 'Product4'], ['Product7', 'Product2', 'Product5']]
```

Might be situation that some paths will be repeated e.g. for list:

```
text = """
7,Product7,DEFAULT,
2,Product2,DEFAULT,7
4,Product4,DEFAULT,7
5,Product4,DEFAULT,7
"""
```

will be (might be multilevel nested paths duplication):

```
[['Product7'], ['Product7', 'Product2'], ['Product7', 'Product4'], ['Product7', 'Product4']]
```

How to get rid of duplicated paths but still having the correct order inside the paths?

Answer (score 1):

```
paths = [['Product7'], ['Product7', 'Product2'], ['Product7', 'Product4'], ['Product7', 'Product4']]

def remove_duplicates(paths):
    new_paths = []
    s = set()
    for path in paths:
        t = tuple(path)
        if t not in s:
            new_paths.append(path)
            s.add(t)
    return new_paths

print(remove_duplicates(paths))
```

Prints:

```
[['Product7'], ['Product7', 'Product2'], ['Product7', 'Product4']]
```

Convert each path to a tuple and check to see if it is already in a set (you cannot add a list to a set hence we convert the list to a tuple). If not, we add the path to our new list of paths and to the set, else we know its a duplicate path.

You don't actually need a separate function to remove duplicates. You can have set of paths, initially empty, and before you append a new path do the type of checking the function `remove_duplicates` is doing:

```
s = set()
def pathsMet(parents, node=''):
    childNodes = parents.get(node)
    if not childNodes:
        return [[]]
    paths = []
    for ID, productName, invoiceType, parentID in childNodes:
        for p in pathsMet(parents, ID):
            path = [productName] + p
            t = tuple(path)
            if t not in s:
                paths.append(path)
                s.add(t)
    return paths
```

Comment: I looked at the other question you posted, [find all possible paths in a tree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597415/find-all-possible-paths-in-a-tree-in-python) and instead of *accepting* the answer that was helpful you just posted a comment thanking the person. That is not what comments are for. You should be accepting answers that satisfy your question so that others see that the question has been satisfactorily answered. See the link on my prior comment.